# How do I prove that such a sequence exists?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have the following question with me:

"Let $a, b$ be integers greater than 2. Prove that there exists a positive integer $k$ and a finite sequence $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$ of positive integers such that $n_1 = a$, $n_k = b$, and $n_in_{i+1}$ is divisible by $n_i + n_{i+1}$ for each $i$ ($1 \le i \le k$)."

The solution for which is given at

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2002_USAMO_Problems/Problem_5

In the above link, there is this step where we have

$a \leftrightarrow \prod_{i=b}^{a}i \leftrightarrow (b-1)^{\lambda} \prod_{i=b}^{a}i \leftrightarrow (b-1)^{\lambda}  \prod_{i=b}^{a}i \cdot \prod_{i=a+1}^{(b-1)^{\lambda}-1} i = X$

The first part is clear since he considers a to be number and uses the property he proves above considering a itself to be a divisor. How does the second part of this step come up? How did he conclude that there does exist such a sequence between $ (b-1)^{\lambda} \prod_{i=b}^{a}i$ and $\prod_{i=b}^{a}i$?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Maybe the solution at https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/usa/usoln/usol025.html is easier to understand? or the one at https://www.maa.org/math-competitions/usamo-2002-solutions ?

Comment: Have you had a look, saisanjeev?

Comment: @GerryMyerson How did he conclude the step he claims to be critical?

Comment: I don't know, saisanjeev, I stopped when I saw $a\leftrightarrow\prod_{i=b}^ai$ and couldn't figure out what it meant. I just thought that if you were having trouble understanding one proof, you might have more luck with a different proof.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the notation is made clear in the link I mentioned in the question

Comment: We expect questions here to be self-contained, and not to require us to go elsewhere to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How did he conclude that there does exist such a sequence between $ (b-1)^{\lambda} \prod_{i=b}^{a}i$ and $\prod_{i=b}^{a}i$?

Let $n=\prod_{i=b}^{a}i$ and $d=b$ and from the solution, we know that $n \leftrightarrow n(d-1)^{\lambda}$ for any $\lambda\in \mathbf{N}$ so $\prod_{i=b}^{a}i  \leftrightarrow (b-1)^{\lambda} \prod_{i=b}^{a}i$.